# Reading inner XML without namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to read inner XML of the root element as string but XmlReader class is namespace aware. Is there any way to ignore the namespaces? I can use any class in BCL as long as it passes the NUNit test below.

```
[Test]
public void GetInnerXmlTest()
{
    string subject = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                     "<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">" +
                         "<url><loc>abc</loc></url>" +
                         "<url><loc>def</loc></url>" +
                     "</urlset>";

    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(subject);
    XmlReader xmlReader = document.FirstNode.CreateReader();
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();
    string innerXml = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
    //<url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><loc>abc</loc></url><url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><loc>def</loc></url>

    Assert.AreEqual("<url><loc>abc</loc></url><url><loc>def</loc></url>",
                    innerXml);
}
```

Comment: Ok then, what result do you get from `ReadInnerXml` and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @OndrejTucny I updated the question with the value returned from ReadInnerXml method. You can see the output I want to get in the assertion.

Comment: these questions maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the namespace first.
[How to remove all namespaces from XML with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987135/how-to-remove-all-namespaces-from-xml-with-c)

You cant just take it out after you have used innerXML.