# XPath without using local-name() or name() functions

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have to parse `oprResult/@code` from below XML using XPath.
The XPath expression

```
//*[local-name()='oprResult']/@code
```

is working as expected, BUT 
I could not use `name` or `local-name` functions as `'('` `')'` are used as delimiter in my parsing function.

Is it possible to parse `oprResult` without `local-name`?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ChangeResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com" code="0" message="Success">
            <oprResult code="0" message="Success"/>
        </ChangeResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You don't have to use predicates (expressions in square brackets) to select elements. Simply specify a path: `//oprResult/@code`. A proper solution would be to fix your "parsing function" to not use parentheses as delimiters.

Comment: `local-name` is necessary when you're trying to ignore namespaces (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath). If that's the case here, use the correct namespace instead.

Comment: //oprResult/@code didn't worked in my case. parsing function change  may affect whole system as there are a no of xpath mapped already for different results. There may be many side effects.


Unfortunately there is no namespace given for 

        <ChangeResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com" code="0" message="Success">
so using namespace is also not possible in this case

Comment: What environment do you use XPath in? Java? There _is_ a namespace defined for `ChangeResponse`, just not with a prefix, since it is a default namespace. But the prefix is irrelevant - depending on the environment you could perhaps register that namespace before applying the XPath expression.

Comment: Oh, and in case I was not clear on this, what I meant was: Show more code, not just the path expression in isolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to parse oprResult without local-name?***

### **Yes<sup>*</sup>**

**Not only is it *possible* to select an XML element without using `local-name()`, it is actually *preferred*.**

One common reason you see example XPaths with constructs such as

```
//*[local-name()='oprResult']
```

is that namespace *declarations* are not an intrinsic part of XPath; namespace and namespace prefix declarations occur in the greater context of the system or language using an XPath library.

If you cannot make your system tolerate the parentheses of `local-name()`, if `//oprResult/@code` doesn't suite, or if you are simply interested in using namespaces properly rather than defeating them, **figure out how to declare a namespace prefix**, say `ex:` for the `http://www.example.com` namespace, and use the namespace prefix in the XPath.  Read on for how...

You do not say what the language and/or library you're using for XPath, but here are a few examples to give a feel for what to look for...

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:ex="http://www.example.com">
   ...
```

**Python (LibXML):**

```
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($xhtml_doc);
$xc->registerNs('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xc->registerNs('ex', 'http://www.example.com');
```

**Javas (SAX):**

```
NamespaceSupport support = new NamespaceSupport();
support.pushContext();
support.declarePrefix("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
support.declarePrefix("ex", "http://www.example.com");
```

### Once you've declared namespace prefixes, your XPath can be:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ex:ChangeResponse/oprResult/@code
```

---

<sup>*</sup>

<sup><sub>...but the reason should not be to avoid parentheses because they "are used as delimiters in a parsing function."  First of all, if an XPath parser is having trouble with embedded parens, get a new XPath parser; if a tool that uses an XPath library is preventing you from using parens, get a new tool (or investigate deeper to be sure the tool is not being used as well as it can be).  Secondly, as @predi observed in the question comments, if there's only a single `oprResult` element and your response is small enough that you don't mind the inefficiency, in your case you can use an XPath without namespaces: `//oprResult/@code`</sub></sup>