# local-name() not working in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>123</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>3dml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/vnd.in3d.3dml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

As you see, it has namespace so default xpath such as `/web-app/mime-mapping/mime-type` will not work.

Based on my reading on various threads,
I tried:

```
/*[local-name()='web-app']/*[local-name()='mime-mapping']/*[local-name()='mime-type']
```

AND

```
/*[name()='web-app']/*[name()='mime-mapping']/*[name()='mime-type']
```

AND

```
/*[name()='web-app' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']/*[name()='mime-mapping' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']/*[name()='mime-type' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']
```

But none seem to work. I am testing in http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html. Also, I am testing in my tool which requires XPath 1.0 and it does not recognize any of the above either.

Any pointers?

Comment: Try a different tester. http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath finds matches.

Comment: But, the tool that I use requires xpath 1.0. Is the specified xpath a 1.0? That tool does not match this xpath either. Can we handle this in any other manner?

Comment: Yes those xpaths are xpath 1.0

Comment: Ok. I will try again.

Comment: @Alohci - I tried in the tool you suggested. But, it does not match any of the three either? It gives below error: `ERROR - Seem there is no XPath provided?`

Comment: Does that require declaring namespace first?

Comment: @praving5: That error indicates that you probably put the XPath in the wrong input field on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your XPath is fine.**

It is your tool  (http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) that is the problem.

Do not use http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html with XML that has a default namespace.  It is noncompliant.  You can see this in the error message that they post for your XML:

> The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always ''
>   and it cannot be redefined to 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'.

Compliant XPath processors will return

```
<mime-type xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3</mime-type>
<mime-type xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">text/vnd.in3d.3dml</mime-type>
```

for your XPath, as expected.

Alternatively, and preferably, [follow best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673129/xpath-namespace-wildcard-best-practice) and define a namespace prefix for the default namespace:

```
j="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
```

and use it in the XPath rather than `local-name()`:

```
/j:web-app/j:mime-mapping/j:mime-type
```

to get the same result properly without skirting namespaces.

Unfortunately, you cannot define a namespace prefix on the Freeformatter site, but you can on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath as well as with [most XPath libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26351614/290085).

Comment: The message that they post is not incorrect. But it is irrelevant when using an xpath like `/*[local-name()='web-app']/*[local-name()='mime-mapping']/*[local-name()='mime-type']`

Comment: @Alohci: The message that they post expresses an important and unfortunate limitation that is relevant to OP's situation.   It is also unfortunate that the site provides no way to defined a namespace prefix so that the XPath can be written properly without resorting to `local-name()`.

Comment: @Alohci: The alternative that you posted in your comment, http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath, does not suffer from the same problem.   And http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php will at least work with the `local-name()`-based XPath, as will most others I've come across.

Comment: Thanks. That is tcserver xml file (web.xml) and I have no control over it as such. I will try what's wrong in my tool. May be it has similar problem like the tester tool.

Comment: Got it. On SLES 11 SP3, we have xpath utility. That does not seem to support namespace-uri. `# xpath  /usr/lib/vmware-vcops/tomcat-web-app/conf/web.xml "/*[name()='web-app' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']/*[name()='mime-mapping' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']/*[name()='mime-type' and namespace-uri()='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee']"
namespace-uri: Function not supported`

Comment: Then I removed, namespace-uri and gave the xpath within "". And it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I was missing "" and it was breaking the xpath processor. Seems weird.

Comment: Your XML is fine too.  **[namespace-uri()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-namespace-uri)** is part of XPath 1.0 and should be supported.  You're having bad luck with tools today.