# Get specific data in xpath

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I need your help, at first I start on code:

bookmod.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
    <insystem>
        <t>asdgas</t>
        <b>asdgas</b>
    </insystem>
    <data>
  <Data name="title">Everyday Italian</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2005</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
  </data>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
    <insystem>
        <t>asdgas</t>
        <b>asdgas</b>
    </insystem>
    <data>

  <Data name="title">Potter Potter</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2003</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
    </data>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
    <insystem>
        <t>asdgas</t>
        <b>asdgas</b>
    </insystem>
    <data>

  <Data name="title">asdgasd Potter</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2005</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
    </data>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
    <insystem>
        <t>asdgas</t>
        <b>asdgas</b>
    </insystem>
    <data>

  <Data name="title">web book</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2005</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
    </data>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}

var x=loadXMLDoc("bookmod.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="/bookstore/book/data/Data";

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
{
xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);
for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
  {
  document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  }
}

// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

while (result)
  {
  document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<br>");
  result=nodes.iterateNext();
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Path I try also :
/bookstore/book/data[Data=2005]/Data[@name='year']

and many other...

It basically means that an XML file is quite large and I need to find only those where `<data name="year">` == 2005

I tried many ways and generators, but still can not deal with it :(

It would have been nice if you could enter a title and author.

---

Edit:

```
<book xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
```

I do not know why but for it not working

Do you know a method to get around this?
when I delete xmlns="..... everything works well but I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath should provide what you need basically with following inputs :
`year`, `title`, `author`.
It is a bit like up and down traversal.

`/bookstore/book/data/Data[@name='year'][.='2005']/preceding-sibling::*[@name='title'][.='Everyday Italian']/following-sibling::*[@name='author'][.='Giada De Laurentiis']/parent::*`

You can replace the `2005`, `Everyday Italian`, `Giada De Laurentiis` with the inputs you like.

The way it works is , it first gets `Data` with `year = 2005` then gets its preceding-sibling which are `title`, `author` then gets matching `title` and then gets its following sibling whose `author` matches given input, finally its parent to return whole `data` element.

Output for the above xpath is :

`'<data>
  <Data name="title">Everyday Italian</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2005</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
</data>'`

Output for a different input : `2003`, `Potter Potter`, `Giada De Laurentiis`

`'<data>
  <Data name="title">Potter Potter</Data>
  <Data name="author">Giada De Laurentiis</Data>
  <Data name="year">2003</Data>
  <Data name="price">30.00</Data>
</data>'`

Comment: In this file all working well but I have a similar file built very similar but does not work for me this method. /Events/Event/data/Data[@Name='day'][.='101']/preceding-sibling::*[@name='Adapter']";

Comment: For the first question please add your new xml so I can take a look to see what might be wrong. for the second one, please use `local-name()` like `//*[local-name()='book']`

Answer (score 2):

The following XPath will select all `book` elements from 2005:

```
/bookstore/book[data/Data[@name='year' and .=2005]]
```

Comment: do you know any debugger ?

Comment: Your edit adds a namespace, which effectively changes the element name of both `book` and its descendants.   You can thwart the namespace by testing `local-name()`, or preferably defining a namespace prefix and using it:  See [**XPath without using local-name() or name() functions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333888/xpath-without-using-local-name-or-name-functions), or ask a new question please.  Thanks.