# Read Array in XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read arrays in an XML, but my code does not return results

XML :

```
<ArrayOfProductoModel
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi.Models">
    <ProductoModel>
        <descripcion>descripcion 1</descripcion>
        <fecha_registro>2016-03-01</fecha_registro>
        <id_producto>1</id_producto>
        <id_proveedor>1</id_proveedor>
        <nombre_producto>producto 1</nombre_producto>
        <precio>200</precio>
    </ProductoModel>
    <ProductoModel>
        <descripcion>descripcion 3</descripcion>
        <fecha_registro>2016-08-02</fecha_registro>
        <id_producto>3</id_producto>
        <id_proveedor>3</id_proveedor>
        <nombre_producto>producto 3</nombre_producto>
        <precio>500</precio>
    </ProductoModel>
</ArrayOfProductoModel>
```

Code :

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(content);
XmlNodeList nodelist = xDoc.SelectNodes("ArrayOfProductoModel/ProductoModel");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("descripcion").InnerText);
}
```

As I can read the array?

Comment: You need to use namespace manager

Comment: I recommend using NewtonSoft and Linq to convert the xml to json. You'll end up with an JArray node which would be easy to work with..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore namespace when selecting XML nodes with XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the imported namespace. You can ignore the namespace as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath):

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(content);

XmlNodeList nodelist = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("*[local-name()='ProductoModel']");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name()='descripcion']").InnerText);
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use an `XmlNamespaceManager` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271689/xml-selectnodes-with-default-namespace-via-xmlnamespacemanager-not-working-as-ex):

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(content);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("MYNS", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi.Models");

XmlNodeList nodelist = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("MYNS:ProductoModel", manager);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
{
     MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("MYNS:descripcion", manager).InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Linq to XML

```
var xml = @"<ArrayOfProductoModel
    xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
    xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi.Models"">
    <ProductoModel>
        <descripcion>descripcion 1</descripcion>
        <fecha_registro>2016-03-01</fecha_registro>
        <id_producto>1</id_producto>
        <id_proveedor>1</id_proveedor>
        <nombre_producto>producto 1</nombre_producto>
        <precio>200</precio>
    </ProductoModel>
    <ProductoModel>
        <descripcion>descripcion 3</descripcion>
        <fecha_registro>2016-08-02</fecha_registro>
        <id_producto>3</id_producto>
        <id_proveedor>3</id_proveedor>
        <nombre_producto>producto 3</nombre_producto>
        <precio>500</precio>
    </ProductoModel>
</ArrayOfProductoModel>";

 var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 var ns = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
 var nodelist = xDoc.Element(ns + "ArrayOfProductoModel").Elements(ns + "ProductoModel");

 foreach (var node in nodelist)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(node.Element(ns + "descripcion").Value);
 }
```

Don't forget to put namespace in front of local name.

Answer (score -1):

At first, I think problem in 
    xDoc.LoadXml(content);
You try:
    xDoc.Load(filePathXml);

Second, I think problem in

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = xDoc.SelectNodes("ArrayOfProductoModel/ProductoModel");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) 
{
        MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("descripcion").InnerText);
}
```

You try:

```
XmlNode rootNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/ArrayOfProductoModel");
 var listProductModel = rootNode.SelectNodes(@"ProductoModel");
foreach (XmlNode node in listProductModel) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(node.SelectSingleNode("descripcion").InnerText);
}
```