# XSL mapping ignoring empty namespace

Tags: xslt, xpath, namespaces

With reference to the post for mapping elements ignoring namespaces:  [How to ignore namespace when selecting XML nodes with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402310/how-to-ignore-namespace-when-selecting-xml-nodes-with-xpath/49121131?noredirect=1#comment85247727_49121131)

Solutions:

```
//*[local-name()='name']
//*:name
```

Have the following question: What about mapping from an element that had empty namespace that got automatically inserted to a request ? Tried the above but it's not picking the empty-namespace elements ...

Thanks

Comment: How about showing us what the XML looks like?

Comment: Both those expressions should select elements in any namespace including elements in no namespace. (I assume you're using "empty namespace" to mean what is technically "no namespace")